# 22.04 server, bind9 logging

Tags: 22.04, apparmor, logging

i used bind9 on 20.04 LTS over years, now upgrade to 22.04 an "copy" the configuration.
bind9 zones and requests works fine as expected, but i have trouble with logging.
including the logging definitions (#include "/etc/bind/named.conf.log";) leads into

```
isc_file_isplainfile '/var/log/bind/bind.log' failed: permission denied
```

and rndc tells me:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

comment out the logging include statement, al things fine.

the apparmor definition is set:

```
/var/log/bind/** rw,
/var/log/bind/ rw,
```

the system permission:

```
sudo chown bind:bind /var/log/bind
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/log/bind
```

I'm confused, what's wrong ...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for anybody with the same problem:

The system service needs to start with -f

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS
```

remove

```
TYPE=forking
```